# How to remove the \homepage symbol in awesome-cv

Tags: fonts, xetex, awesome-cv

I'm writing up my resume right now. My code looks like this:

```
\name{}{John Doe}  
\email{John_Doe@gmail.com}
\mobile{839-839-8399}
```

and the output currently looks like this:

[image]

But when I add `\homepage`, the symbol pops up, as following:

[image]

Is there a way to remove the home symbol?

Comment: Please do add minimal working example

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Yes, there is..

Comment: Welcome, there are also symbols in front of the phone number, email and others.You already removed them, managed to get different fonts. It is not even clear which/what template you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the command which prints the icon.  Also keep in mind that these "templates" are only to be filled with content.  They are not designed to be changed.

```
\documentclass{awesome-cv}
\name{}{John Doe}  
\email{John\_Doe@gmail.com}
\mobile{839-839-8399}
\homepage{johndoe.com}

\def\faHome{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\makecvheader
\end{document}
```

[image]