# How to remove the \email, \mobile and \linkedin symbols in awesome-cv

Tags: awesome-cv

I don't want the symbols to show up on my resume. I would like to input simple text containing my email address, phone number and linkedin URl.

Answer (score 0):

(From the answer to a similar question here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369943/120578
and the `.cls` file)

You have to set (in your preamble):

```
\def\faEnvelope{\ignorespaces}
\def\faMobile{\ignorespaces}
\def\faLinkedinSquare{\ignorespaces}
```